# Python - Pandas, Split time series dataframe per week

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns that are filled with timestamps along with their corresponding values. The df has around 7000 rows (2 months data) and I wanted to split them into smaller dataframes for each week. I can split them of course into days etc but I don't know about weeks. The dataframe looks like this:

```
2018-08-29T00:03:09      12310                  
2018-08-29T00:08:10      21231              
2018-08-29T00:13:10      19.6                   
2018-08-29T00:18:10     19321                   
2018-08-29T00:23:10     182134                  
2018-08-29T00:28:10     172319                  
2018-08-29T00:33:10     1734                    
2018-08-29T00:38:10     1764                    
2018-08-29T00:43:10     169743                  
2018-08-29T00:48:10     16747                   
2018-08-29T00:53:10     17830
```

Thanks, everyone in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Consider below df:

```
In [2712]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[2712]: 
                  Date      Value
0  2018-08-29 00:03:09  12,310.00
1  2018-08-29 00:08:10  21,231.00
2  2018-08-29 00:13:10      19.60
3  2018-08-29 00:18:10  19,321.00
4  2018-08-29 00:23:10 182,134.00
5  2018-08-29 00:28:10 172,319.00
6  2018-08-29 00:33:10   1,734.00
7  2018-08-29 00:38:10   1,764.00
8  2018-08-29 00:43:10 169,743.00
9  2018-08-29 00:48:10  16,747.00
10 2018-08-29 00:53:10  17,830.00

In [2711]: df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
In [2714]: df['week'] = df['Date'].dt.week

In [2715]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[2715]: 
                  Date      Value  week
0  2018-08-29 00:03:09  12,310.00    35
1  2018-08-29 00:08:10  21,231.00    35
2  2018-08-29 00:13:10      19.60    35
3  2018-08-29 00:18:10  19,321.00    35
4  2018-08-29 00:23:10 182,134.00    35
5  2018-08-29 00:28:10 172,319.00    35
6  2018-08-29 00:33:10   1,734.00    35
7  2018-08-29 00:38:10   1,764.00    35
8  2018-08-29 00:43:10 169,743.00    35
9  2018-08-29 00:48:10  16,747.00    35
10 2018-08-29 00:53:10  17,830.00    35
```

Now group the df on `week`.

```
In [2717]: grp = df.groupby('week') 

In [2721]: for x,y in grp: 
      ...:     print(x,y) 
      ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
35                Date      Value  week
0  2018-08-29 00:03:09  12,310.00    35
1  2018-08-29 00:08:10  21,231.00    35
2  2018-08-29 00:13:10      19.60    35
3  2018-08-29 00:18:10  19,321.00    35
4  2018-08-29 00:23:10 182,134.00    35
5  2018-08-29 00:28:10 172,319.00    35
6  2018-08-29 00:33:10   1,734.00    35
7  2018-08-29 00:38:10   1,764.00    35
8  2018-08-29 00:43:10 169,743.00    35
9  2018-08-29 00:48:10  16,747.00    35
10 2018-08-29 00:53:10  17,830.00    35
```

This will give you smaller dataframes for each week.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am trying to test if it's working but I still get an error though. I'll give some code lines to explain: 

//import datetime 
//timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") //print(timestamp.dt.week) 

//The error i got was: "AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'dt'"

Comment: I don't think the code which you are running matches what I have put in my answer. Please check carefully.

Comment: Ohh yeah that was my mistake! Sorry about that! Everything works great. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
df['Week'] = df['timestamp'].dt.to_period('W-MON')
```

And you get a week column in your dataframe. Then if you want to browse through the weeks:

```
for w, data in df.groupby('Week'):
    print(w, data)
```

You can also query the week containing certain days like this:

```
df[df['Week']=='2018-08-29']
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing it

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['time']), inplace=True)
df['week']=df.index.week
```

Explanation

```
 #pd.to_datetime(df['time'])- Coerces time to datetime
    #df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['time']), inplace=True)#Sets time as index
    #df.index.week; extracts time period from the index
```

[image]